# Weekdays appearing are wrong in custom calendar created in android

Tags: android

In my application i am displaying a calendar of days in a horizontal scrollable listview like below : 
[image]

The dates are proper and the current date is also selected, the issue i am facing is the week day that is displayed.It is not proper. The code written to displayed this kind of calendar is as follows:

```
int count = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= noOfDays; i++) {

        int year = Calendar.YEAR;
        int month = Calendar.MONTH;
        int day = i;

        Calendar c = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, day);

        c.set(year, month, day);
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");

        String d = sdf.format(cal1.getTime());

        CustomData custom = new CustomData(String.valueOf(i),
                getWeekday(c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)), d);

        mCustomData[count] = custom;
        Log.e("mCustomData", d);
        count++;
        if(Integer.parseInt(splitDateee[0])==i)
        {
            currentDate = i-1;
        }


    }
```

There is an error in weekdays that is being displayed. What am i missing here? Not able to figure out the issue.
Please help ! Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int year = Calendar.YEAR;
int month = Calendar.MONTH;
```

These are flags belonging to calendar to get and set values, and do not indicate the current year and month. You would need to get the year and month from the current device time and do:

```
int year = currentYear;
int month = currentMonth;
```

Calling `Calendar.getInstance()` gets the calendar for the current day:

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
```

You can then use the flags like so:

```
int month = now.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int year = now.get(Calendar.YEAR);
```